# Pygame event module vs key module for player movement

Tags: python, events, pygame, key

My goal is a 2 player pygame played on one keyboard where each player can move up, down, left and right.

I wonder if it is preferable to use only the event module or also the key module for this.
Most examples I've seen only use the key module, like so:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = -5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 5
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 0
x += x_change
```

The problem with this: When left and right are pressed at the same time and then one key is lifted, x_change is set to zero.

I tried fixing this with a variable that tracks how many keys are pressed, but no success. So I am wondering if the above method is just not the proper way to do it. I have hope that the pygame.key module solves my problem but have problems understanding the documentation.

Anyone with pygame experience here who can recommend when to use which module?

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement:

```py
speed = 5
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * speed
    y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * speed

    # [...]
```